# cant delete row from database unit test in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

I´m testing a delete method in my service class and it won't delete the rows from the database. When I use the same method when the application runs it works fine. I'm using MySQL and H2database plugin to test the app. The other CRUD testing methods work just fine.

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class StudentAccountApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    StudentAccountService studentAccountService;

     @Test
        public void testStudentAccountDeletion(){
            Student student1 = new Student ("john","smith","studying");
            Student student2 = new Student ("will","ferrel","finished");
            Student student3 = new Student ("louis","johnsson","finished");

            StudentAccount studentAccount1 = new StudentAccount ("josm","josm","studying", student1 );
            StudentAccount studentAccount2 = new StudentAccount ("wife","wife","studying", student2);
            StudentAccount studentAccount3 = new StudentAccount ("lojo","lojo","studying", student3);

            studentService.save(student1);
            studentService.save(student2);
            studentService.save(student3);

            studentAccountService.save(studentAccount1);
            studentAccountService.save(studentAccount2);
            studentAccountService.save(studentAccount3);

            List<StudentAccount> studentAccountsToDelete = studentAccountService.getStudentAccountsFromFinishedStudents();

            studentAccountService.deleteStudentAccountsFromFinishedStudents(studentAccountsToDelete);

            List<StudentAccount> studentAccountsAfterDeletion = studentAccountService.getAllStudentAccounts();

            assertEquals(1, studentAccountsAfterDeletion.size());
        }
}
```

**StudentAccountServiceImpl**

```
    public class StudentAccountServiceImpl implements StudentAccountService {
   @Autowired
    StudentAccountRepository studentAccountRepository;
        @Override
        public void deleteStudentAccount(StudentAccount studentToDelete) {
            studentAccountRepository.delete(studentToDelete);
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteStudentAccountsFromFinishedStudents(List<StudentAccount> studentAccountsToDelete) {
            studentAccountsToDelete.forEach(studentAccount -> {
                deleteStudentAccount(studentAccount);
            });
        }
    }
```

The test fails because the student accounts are not getting deleted so the list size is 3 instead of 1. As stated before, the method `studentAccountsToDelete`works normally when the application runs. I don´t know what's the difference here if all of the other CRUD methods work. My guess is that there is an issue with the H2database. Need some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there other tests that can interfere with the result (do you start the test with an empty dB)?

Comment: @Lesiak The database is created when I run the project from localhost. When I run the test the database is created from the unit test creating those three rows. I autowire another interface `StudentService` to persist the students to the database. I tried erasing the previously created database but the error is still there.

Comment: What I meant is another test method can add some data (even if you launch entire suite with an empty dB)

Comment: @Lesiak yes i have three more test methods in this test class

Comment: You probably checked that, but does the error happen if you execute only this one test method, and not entire test class? On top of that, check generated sql.

Comment: yes only with this test method. In fact, it doesn't even run the delete sql query

Comment: Can you share deleteStudentAccountsFromFinishedStudents definition?

Comment: @Lesiak added the definition you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The answer is in the entity where the mapping occurs. It seems that this is a common mistake when using one to many mapping so in the entity

**I changed this:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<StudentAccount> studentAccounts;
```

**To this:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", orphanRemoval=true)
    private Collection<StudentAccount> studentAccounts;
```

Notice that i replaced `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` for `orphanRemoval=true` this is telling hibernate to remove a reference to an object that no longer exists. This is very useful for cleaning up dependent objects. In my case, a student that finished his career does no longer need a student account. I hope this answer helps someone. 
Cheers